# Using Htaccess Error document with absolute path

Tags: .htaccess

I am using htaccess error document with absolute path instead of relative path.
The code is

```
ErrorDocument 404 http://www.sitename.com/404page.html
```

Is it OK to use it like this or should it must be

```
ErrorDocument 404 /404page.html
```

I have some advantages in doing as absolute path ? Could you please tell me if it is OK.

Answer (score 0):

It should be:

```
ErrorDocument 404 /404page.html
```

Which is an absolute path, just without the hostname. You can't have this (relative path):

```
ErrorDocument 404 404page.html
```